# Can not reallocate memory in a very peculiar circumstance

Tags: c, unix, memory, memory-management, realloc

Almost minimal reproducible example:

> prog.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
char *buffer;
int c;
size_t bufsiz = 1024, i = 0;

if (!(buffer = malloc(bufsiz))) {
    fputs("malloc() failed!\n", stderr);
    return 1;
}

while (EOF != (c = fgetc(stdin))) {
    buffer[i] = c;
    if (++i == bufsiz && !(buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsiz *= 2))) {
        fputs("realloc() failed! (loop)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
}
buffer[i] = '\0';

if (!(buffer = realloc(buffer, i))) {
    fputs("realloc() failed! ", stderr);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", i);
    return 1;
}

fputs(buffer, stdout);
return 0;
}
```

I use this command to compile and run:

```
gcc prog.c -o prog
```

This command copies the content of `prog.c` to `exp` as expected:

```
cat prog.c | ./prog > exp
```

This command prints the error message “realloc() failed! 0”:

```
cat prog.c | ./prog > prog.c
```

I have yet to find out the reason behind this peculiar behavior...

P.S.: I am using GNU cat and bash

Comment: Is `i` 0 by any chance, because that command deletes your program?

Comment: I added `fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", i);` in the last `if`'s body and yes, it printed out `0`.

Comment: Where does your program put a null character at the end of the string in the buffer?

Comment: Most operators in a single line wins a cookie! "If i equals buffsize AND realloc returns NULL". Surely not your intention?

Comment: @EricPostpischil right after the while loop.

Comment: @Lundin What do you mean?

Comment: What does realloc's manual page say about allocating 0 bytes?

Comment: @Lundin: I think that line is correct.  If `i == bufsiz` it will attempt to realloc, and if this fails it reports the error and aborts.  However, I agree it's not the clearest way to write it.

Comment: Like I said, most operators in a single line wins a cookie, or possibly wins the whole prestigious IOCCC.

Comment: @user253751 How do I open the man page of a `C` function?

Comment: @beardeadclown `man realloc`......?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cat prog.c | ./prog > prog.c`, the shell parses the command, sees there is a redirection into `prog.c`, and opens `prog.c` for writing, which erases any previous contents of the file. Then `cat prog.c` sees an empty file and copies it to standard output. `./prog` faithfully reproduces this empty stream.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you've (re-)discovered a bug in your system's implementation of `realloc`, whereby "success" resizing to 0 is indistinguishable from an error. As specified, if `realloc` returns a null pointer, it has failed and the old object still exists. But some historical implementations treat `realloc(p,0)` as `free(p)`. Future versions of the C standard allow for this behavior, and deprecate the use of `realloc` with a zero size, so if you want to use `realloc` like this you should make sure you are not passing a zero size.

As noted by Eric Postpischil in a comment:

> Where does your program put a null character at the end of the string in the buffer?

the fact that 0 is a possible size for your buffer is indicative of a problem - you forgot to reserve space for terminating the string - and if you fix this, even a zero-length string takes a nonzero number of bytes.

Comment: It's valid for malloc & friends to return non-null upon a malloc(0) request. C17 7.22.3. "If the size of the space requested is
zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned to indicate an error,
or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."

Comment: But why is `i` zero when outputing to `cat`ed file , but not when outputing to different one?

Comment: @Lundin: It's not valid to free the object on an error, though.

Comment: @beardeadclown: Because you truncated it by redirecting output to it.

Comment: What makes you think it was freed? `buffer = realloc(buffer,0)` might return either NULL or a pointer to crap, in either case original pointer will get lost when that happens. If you have a backup of `buffer` elsewhere, then nothing should have been freed.

Comment: @Lundin: Because I'm aware of the behavior of the real-world implementations that do this, and they free it. Indeed there's no evidence in OP's post that it was freed, and it would be a valid, albeit bad, implementation of `realloc` to have it fail for `n=0` (and leave the object unfreed).

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Ah you are correct, just tried it on all the mainstream compilers and they all corrupt/free the original data. Curious.